# Rails console inexplicable fails to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason, my Rails console on my live server is now failing to load.  I pulled a new branch down, force checked out the new branch (possibly a bad idea) as nothing really should change on the live server (in theory), and in both the new branch and on master I have the follwoing error when trying to run the console:

```
/home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find pg-0.11.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:60:in `setup'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /home/pastonpaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@pastonpaper/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

Really no idea how to troubleshoot this. It seems to be a gem issue, but how could this have changed?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: It can't find the pg-0.11.0 gem. Do a 'gem list' and look for it. Is it there?  Since you whacked two source trees, I agree it's a GEM issue (the one thing in common).  You could try 'bundle update'

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I ran bundle install which failed on the pg-0.11.0 gem.  Looking in the Gemfile I noticed it had gem 'pg' under production which presumably shouldn't be there, as using mysql.  So edited that out, ran bundle install and that solved the problems.  Rails still completely terrifies me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has something to do with the postres gem (pg). Maybe you need to run `bundle install` or check your Gemfile (and Gemfile.lock) for anything unusual.